# MVC3 error message: .cshtml The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have deployed mvc3 application in IIS 7

It is running as integrated .net 4 mode.  Can anyone please guide?

Error message is: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden

Comment: What's your request URL? .NET framework on app pool set to .net 4.0?

Comment: yes. set to .net 4. url is: http://localhost:1111/test/home/index.cshtml. test is an application within the website

Comment: also i did bin deployment by taking all dependencies assemblies

Comment: Ah ok, you shouldn't directly request with the razor extension, you would request the default routing, somecontroller/someaction i.e. http://localhost:1111/test/home/index

Comment: Another thing is make sure `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` is in web.config under `<system.webserver>` node

Comment: home/index says that the resource could not be found. i have got runAllModules tag too but no luck

Comment: Can you post the RegisterRoutes method from your Global.asax?

Comment: Can you post your dependency list? Make sure they are like the following: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

Comment: yes iv copied same dlls. here is the code routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - As programad asked, can you post your routes?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- If IIS was installed after .NET 4.0 on the server you need to run [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) to register it with IIS
- The application pool is set to run in integrated mode
- In your web.config you have the `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` set
- You are accessing your site with `http://server/home/index` (change the controller and action names to match yours).
- You have a route that will match the `{controller}/{action}` url in your `Global.asax`.
- The corresponding view exists in `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`.